# AS3 Air app needs to continue running in the background

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am developing an app for iOS and Android that monitors a users locations and plots a course with markers every 10 seconds or so however when the phone is locked the location stops tracking and plotting the positions stop.

I have added UIBackgroundModes to location and also .executeInBackground = true.

Anything I could be missing?

Comment: You can get location updtates when in background.  After your app goes to background, there's a second deactivate event, make sure you code for that.  All explained here http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/04/air-ios-background-behavior/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask this permission.

Yet the IOS is through incosistente this sense, not necessarily you'll get an update every 10 seconds.

Permission -> Background Location Updates

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Permission -> Background Location Updates. Latest research suggests because I am using render mode = direct then when the app goes in to background it stops all running tasks.